# accessing the parent of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, oop

I'm trying to call methods on the parent of my object by passing the parent in as property.
But i keep getting this error:

> expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'Wheel'

```
@interface Car : NSObject {
    Wheel *w;
}

- (void)doCarStuff;

@end

@implementation Car
- (id)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //w = [[Wheel alloc] init];
        //w.parent = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)doCarStuff {
    NSLog(@"Car stuff");
}
@end

@interface Wheel : NSObject {
    Car *parent;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) Car *parent;

@end

@implementation Wheel
@synthesize parent;

- (id)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        [parent doCarStuff];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

It is probably because i have to declare the Car before the Wheel and vise versa.
I bet the solution is so simple i can't see it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward-declare Wheel before Car.

```
@class Wheel;

@interface Car : ...
```

(BTW, in Wheel's `-init` method, `parent` is not initialized (thus always `nil`), therefore calling `[parent doCarStuff]` there is useless.)

Comment: Now i get this error, wich is even more confusing.

ld: duplicate symbol .objc_class_name_Wheel in ..
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1